# Is locking needed for code executing PS commands in a Runspace?

Tags: c#, powershell, thread-safety, runspace

A Java guy is trying to learn some C# by diving into some existing C# code, checking user credentials with PowerShell.

The code below which I am trying to understand is in the context of possible performance problems.

The method below, `CheckCredentials()`, is called quite often and seem to be stuck for long periods of time, 60 seconds and more. My first suspect, of course, is the `lock()` part. I fail to understand why the lock is needed, if it is.

According to the docs, `InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()`and `RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()` are thread safe as they are public static methods (relevant sections [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace(v=vs.85).aspx))

All objects used in the method are created anew; the only shared variables are `_lock` (and I am not sure why it is there at all) and `modulePath`. So, essentially, only the `modulePath` can be accessed by multiple threads. But, that doesn't seem like a problem. It's only a path, and the code is importing a PS module.

My question is: does the code below need to be "locked" at all?

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();
private readonly string modulePath;

public async Task<bool> CheckCredentials(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        // Create Initial Session State for runspace.
        var initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { modulePath });

        // Create credential object.
        var credential = GetPowerShellCredential(username, password);

        // Create command to connect office 365.
        var connectCommand = new Command("Connect-MsolService");

        connectCommand.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("Credential", credential)));

        lock(_lock)
        {
            using (var psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession))
            {
                psRunSpace.Open();
                psRunSpace.Invoke(connectCommand);                        
            }
            return true;
        };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Info("Failed to check credentials.", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```